# The Lie derivative as a limit of a curve in $ \mathrm TM $

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $ M $ be a smooth manifold, let $ p\in M $ and let $ X\in \mathscr X(M) $ be a fixed vector field on $ M $. Given some other vector field $ Y $ the *Lie derivative* of $ X $ along $ Y $ evaluated at the point $ p $ is defined as the limit
$$
(L_YX)\rvert_p = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\mathrm T_{\Phi_t^Y(p)}(\Phi_{-t}^Y)\circ X_{\Phi_t^Y(p)} - X_p}{t}
$$
in $ \mathrm T_pM $ where the dot denotes function application and
$$
\mathrm T_{\Phi_t^Y(p)}(\Phi_{-t}^Y)\colon \mathrm T_{\Phi_t^Y(p)}M\to \mathrm T_pM
$$
is the tangent map at the point $ \Phi_t^Y(p) $ of the diffeomorphism
$$
\Phi_t^Y\colon M\to M
$$
induced by the flow of $ Y $. This way we obtain another vector in $ \mathrm T_pM $.

But what if we consider the curve
$$
\lambda(t) = \mathrm T_{\Phi_t^Y(p)}(\Phi_{-t}^Y)\circ X_{\Phi_t^Y(p)} - X_p
$$
on the manifold $ \mathrm TM $ (the tangent bundle) and take its derivative at $ 0 $? In this way we obtain a vector $ \dot\lambda(0) $ in the tangent space $ \mathrm T_{0_p}(\mathrm TM) $, where $ 0_p\in \mathrm T_pM $ is the null vector.

Are the Lie derivative $ (L_YX)\rvert_p $ and $ \dot\lambda(0) $ somewhat related objects?

Comment: Why are you writing $\circ$ for *evaluating* the derivative map on a tangent vector?

Comment: I find it confusing to write $ \mathrm T_{\Phi_t^Y(p)}(\Phi_{-t}^Y)(X_{\Phi_t^Y(p)}) $ -too much parentheses. As for why the $ {\circ} $: my linear algebra course used $ {\circ} $ to denote the canonical duality pairing between a vector space $ V $ and its dual $ V^* $, so that if $ \phi\colon V\to W $ then $ \phi^*(\beta)\circ v = \beta\circ \phi\circ v $ can be read in the two ways $ (\beta\circ \phi)\circ v $ and $ \beta \circ (\phi\circ v) $. I kept using it mostly because of laziness.

Comment: Also, if you know about generalized elements in category theory you will convey that sometimes it's a useful notation. But it can be confusing in this context, yeah.

Comment: I am (was) a complex differential geometer and have had only the most remote contacts with category theory. Your linear algebra course used notation that in 50+ years as a mathematician I have never seen elsewhere. By the way, if you use $f_*$ or $Df$ instead of $T(f)$, that removes some of the unnecessary parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, $(L_YX)|_p$ and $\dot\lambda (0)$ are the same object. Denoting by $\pi:TM\to M$ the bundle projection, the curve $\lambda$ by definition has the property that $\pi\circ \lambda$ is the constant map $p$. (So indeed, $\lambda$ can be viewed as a curve in the tangent space $T_pM$.) Differentiating this at $t=0$, you see that $\lambda'(0)$ lies in the kernel $\ker(T_{\lambda(0)}\pi)\subset T_{\lambda(0)}M$ and $\lambda(0)=0$ by construction. So actually $\lambda'(0)$ lies in the so-called vertical subbundle $V_{0_p}(TM)$. It is a standard result that the vertical subbundle of a vector bundle is isomorphic to the pulback of the bundle to its own total space, i.e. $V(TM)=\pi^*TM$, so the fiber $V_{0_p} TM$ is naturally identified with the $T_pM$ and under this identification $\lambda'(0)$ corresponds to $(L_YX)|_p$. In fact, the identification of the Vertical subbundle with a pullback is completely analogous to the identification of the tangent spaces to a vector space with the vector space itself. Otherwise put, vor $X,v\in T_pM$ the tangent vector in $V_X(TM)\subset T_XTM$ corresponding to $v$ is the derivative at $0$ of the smooth curve $t\mapsto X+tv$.

Defining the Lie derivative via a limit in $T_pM$ (or via a curve in $T_pM$, which amounts to the same thing) is just a simple way to avoid going through these identifications.

Comment: It took me a while to make sense of the vertical-bundle-as-$ \ker(\mathrm T\pi) $ construction but it's almost all clear now! Just a question. It's clear how to define a map $ \mathrm T_{\pi (X)}M\to \mathrm V_X(\mathrm TM) $ (just send the curve you picked to its tangent vector in $ \mathrm T_X(\mathrm TM) $). But how do you define its inverse? Of course you can't map $ V\in \mathrm V_X(\mathrm TM) $ in its image by $  \mathrm T_X\pi\colon \mathrm T_XM\to \mathrm T_{\pi(X)}M $ since this thing is always equal to zero.

Comment: I am not sure whether there is a simple natural way to write the inverse. But that is already true for the tangent space of a vector space: It is easy to get an isomorphism $V\to T_vV$ for any $v\in V$, but I would not know a simple way to write the inverse (except for saying that it is the inverse of the given map). What comes closest is to observe that a tangent vector in $V_X(TM)$ can be obtained as the derivative of a curve through $X$ that stays in $T_{\pi(X)}M$ and then take the derivative of that curve in the vector space as an element of the vector space.